# Angular 6 Using router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular6, router-outlet

I am trying to understand how named outlets work in Augular 6. I want to be able to break up a page into multiple sections and have that page dynamically display different content based on multiple named outlets provided by the route path configuration. I am not seeing any debug information, and I haven't be able to locate the problem.

Example:

app.component.html

```
<!--<app-basic></app-basic> -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<h1>hello</h1>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

router module I have the following:

```
{
  path: 'schedule-inspection',
  component: ScheduleInspectionComponent,
  children: 
  [
    {
      path: 'add',
      component: SidebarScheduleInspectionComponent,
      outlet: 'sidebar',
    },
  ],
},
```

Result is page is loading the parent component, and displays hello. No content is displayed out of the named outlet.

It seems logical that  you should be able to do this. If there is a different approach that you be taken here other than using the router please advise, but it seems like the right approach for what I am trying to do.

Comment: are you hitting the url schedule-inspection/add

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are mixing child routes and aux (named) routes. You don't define aux routes with the `children` property. See also this post: [Child Routing for Angular 5 not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501471/child-routing-for-angular-5-not-working-properly/51508525#51508525)

So something like this:

```
{
  path: 'schedule-inspection',
  component: ScheduleInspectionComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'add',
  component: SidebarScheduleInspectionComponent,
  outlet: 'sidebar',
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do the following, which isn't what I would expect. I was hoping/thinking that if you could define the path for the url in such a way that it would know how to fill out the other router-outlets.

```
Working:

{ path: 'schedule-inspection-sidebar', component: ServiceAreaComponent, outlet:'sidebar' },
{
  path: 'schedule-inspection',
  component: ScheduleInspectionComponent
},
{
    path: 'schedule-inspection(sidebar:schedule-inspection-sidebar)',
    component: SidebarScheduleInspectionComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
},
```

Then in the browser go to schedule-inspection(sidebar:schedule-inspection-sidebar) it will then look for a path named schedule-inspection-sidebar and also display the main content. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

I wanted to be able to go to /schedule-inspection, and since it had a named router-outlet that it would be able to locate and display that content based on it's definition. The end user will never directly go to schedule-inspection-sidebar.

As a work around I guess I could build the logic into the sidebar component as far as what component to display and not use the router-outlet. I was thinking the router could manage that functionality instead of using if statements.